# Cant change back button title of navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, back-button, ios7.1

I have UITableViewController and I want to change the title of back button to "Zpět". So I change back button bar on storyboard, but nothing happend...I tried also use this code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"Zpět";
```

I insert the code in function ViewWillAppear, but nothing happend. I also tried function ViewDidLoad and initWithStyle. The same result..I see in simulator still "Back". I also tried this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = 
        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"NewTitle" 
                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                        target:nil 
                                        action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:newBackButton];
[newBackButton release];
```

Also nothing..Why?

[image]

Comment: Are you setting in the correct view Controller ??

Comment: Put this piece of code in viewdidload method of whichever view controller's back button title you want to change, rather than the view that you would be seeing.

Comment: Do you maybe want to enable a different language (czech i guess)? If you add a language to your project settings, your users will automatically get the translated texts for system buttons (like the back button). There are a lot of tutorials on that topic.. e.g. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/

Comment: SHabbir: Yes I'm.. Magnus: I don't understand your answer exactly. Martin: Thanks. It's interesting and I tried it, I added a czech to location. In storyboardstring(czech) I see in all View title of back button as "Zpět", but 5 out of 12 I see in simulator "Back", the rest have "Zpět". I'm really confused of that. I though, that is something in cache, but wasn't...

Comment: You need to use: `setTitle: forState:`, you can not simply change the title property. Setting the title property only will eventually cause the button to reset it's title.

Comment: I hope my answer can help you

Answer (score 0):

In the view that opens your `UITableViewController` add this code before the segue:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Zpět" 
                                                               style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                              target: nil 
                                                              action: nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: backButton];
```

then you can force the segue with (only if needed):

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourID" sender:sender];
```

In fact doing that once, all the `UINavigationController` back buttons will have "Zpět" as text.